# jQuery UI draggable - how to drag a group of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

What is the best practice to drag several separate containers by some handle inside one of these draggable areas (using jQuery UI)? So, one of the containers should be master, and the rest should be its slaves.

I've only found [this](http://www.myphpetc.com/2009/11/jquery-ui-multiple-draggable-plugin.html) jQuery UI plugin, but the main issue with it is that it uses the only class "ui-multidraggable" for all the containers, so I can't create several separate draggable groups. For now, the only solution for me is to modify this plugin to pass groups of slave $ nodes into options.